# How to put class in constructor parameter | PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I have a question about OOP with PowerShell. I have two classes, Termination and Employee. I want Termination to accept an instance of class Employee as a constructor parameter. VSCode is giving me this error:

"Unable to find type [Employee].PowerShell
Ignoring 'TypeNotFound' parse error on type 'Employee'. Check if the specified type is correct. This can also be due the type not being known at parse time due to types imported by 'using' statements.PSScriptAnalyzer(TypeNotFound)"

[image: Syntax error]

```
class Termination {

# Properties
[Employee] $employee

Termination([Employee] $Employee) {
    $this.employee = $employee
}
```

Structure of project:
[image]

Using version 5.1.14393.3866

Comment: You do not appear to have included the error you are receiving, and when pasting code, it may be better for people trying to assist if you copy the code and paste it here with formatting, so they can better read, copy, and run the code in their own environments.

Comment: What Powershell version are you using?

Comment: @derloopkat I am using version 5.1.14393.3866

Comment: Where is the employee class?

Comment: @DougMaurer I have added a screenshot to show folder structure. It is in a separate folder..

Comment: @DougMaurer Oh I think you're onto something. If I copy the Employee class into the Termination.ps1 file it recognizes it and gets rid of the error. How can I reference the Employee.ps1 file in the other folder? Thank you

Comment: using module  https://stephanevg.github.io/powershell/class/module/DATA-How-To-Write-powershell-Modules-with-classes/

Answer (score 3):

Save employee class file as psm1 and then

```
using module C:\temp\employee.psm1

class Termination {

# Properties
[Employee] $employee

Termination([Employee] $Employee) {
    $this.employee = $employee
    }
}
```

Comment: That worked, thank you! Is it possible to use a dynamic path so I dont have to hard code the absolute path in there? I have a dev and prod environment and it would be ideal if I didnt have to update the paths every time I push to prod..

Comment: You can use `using module .\path\relative\from\current\file.psm1`.  The `.` works like `$PSScriptRoot` (though only in this syntax). Note that unless you're targeting PowerShell 7.1.0-preview3 or later you *must* use \ and not /, otherwise it'll switch to relative to working directory paths due to a bug.